# phone number validation in check_phone function

Tags: php, mysql, database, validation, phpmyadmin

I have a signup.php file with a script that does validation for username and email. I have added a phone number field in the php file and added it in the database too as varchar(15). Everything is working fine but it accepts any crap entered in the field. What syntax should I add in the below script to validate phone number?

Required validation
*The textbox should allow 11 digit number as input. 
*If user enters a 10 digit number, in the database it should update the database table field as +91 followred by the 10 digit number
*If user enters a 11 digit number starting with 0, it should remove the zero and update the database table field as +91 followred by the 10 digit number (removing the 0)
*alphabets and special character not allowed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_username(){
    var b=$('#username').val();
    if(b.length<3){
        $('#username').css('border','2px solid #a50000')
    }else{
        $.get("system/ajax.php?a=checkUser",{data:b},function(a){
            if(a==1){
                $('#username').css('border','2px solid #00a500')
            }else{
                $('#username').css('border','2px solid #a50000')
            }
        })
    }
}
function check_email(){
    var b=$('#email').val();
    if(b.length<3){
        $('#email').css('border','2px solid #a50000')
    }else{
        $.get("system/ajax.php?a=checkEmail",{data:b},function(a){
            if(a==1){$('#email').css('border','2px solid #00a500')
            }else{
                $('#email').css('border','2px solid #a50000')
            }
        })
    }
}
function check_email2(){
    var a=new RegExp(/^(("[\w-+\s]+")|([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*)|("[\w-+\s]+")([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*))(@((?:[\w-+]+\.)*\w[\w-+]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][\d]\.|1[\d]{2}\.|[\d]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    var b=$('#email').val();
    var c=$('#email2').val();
    if(!a.test(c)){
        $('#email2').css('border','2px solid #a50000')
    }else if(b==c){
        $('#email2').css('border','2px solid #00a500')
    }else{
        $('#email2').css('border','2px solid #a50000')
    }
} 
</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please post the you've tried so far.

Comment: I searched for it and found that I have to put this somewhere [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] and prefix it with +91. I also understood that the border color changes to green if the validation is met and turns red if it doesnt and wrote $db->Query("INSERT INTO `users`(email,phone,login,country,sex) values('".$email."','".$phn."','".$name."','".$country."','".$gender."')"); to insert it in database. Need help in writing validation and how to prefix +91 in the insert into statement

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use Google's libphonenumber: https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your primary validation should be done in PHP, not in JavaScript. Even if you fix the JavaScript code, any visitor who comes along can just disable JavaScript and enter anything they want in the fields.

To validate the phone number in PHP, try the following:

```
<?php
function validatePhoneNumber($num) {
    if (!ctype_digit($num)) {
        return false;
    }
    $len = strlen($num);
    if ($len === 11) {
        if ($num[0] === "0") {
            return "+91" . substr($num, 1);
        } else {
            return $num;
        }
    } else if ($len === 10) {
        return "+91" . $num;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

The function `validatePhoneNumber` will return `false` if the phone number is invalid. Otherwise, it will return the parsed phone number as a string.

Use it like this:

```
<?php
validatePhoneNumber("4455");        // false
validatePhoneNumber("(55)5555555"); // false
validatePhoneNumber("5518843371");  // "+915518843371"
validatePhoneNumber("04113313311"); // "+914113313311"
validatePhoneNumber("14355555555"); // "143555555555"
?>
```

Comment: Thank you.... I already have a line.... $phn = $db->EscapeString($_POST['phone1']); in the signup.php file. Can I change this line to $phn = $db->EscapeString($_POST[validatePhoneNumber('phone1')]); ? I have pasted the function at the bottom of the signup.php file. Is this okay?

Comment: Actually, validation should be done in _both_ JavaScript and PHP.  Validating in JS gives the non-malcious user, which is almost everyone, snappy feedback, lets the input box be colored as described in the question, and lets the server check for a standardized number.  Validation on the server is necessary because, as you point out, client validation cannot be trusted.

Comment: @user3736026 That would call the `validatePhoneNumber` function on the string `"phone1"`. You need to call it on the actual number that was provided, so you should use: `$phn = validatePhoneNumber($_POST['phone1'])`. Use `if ($phn === false)` to see if the phone number is invalid. If it's not false, then it's a valid number and you can then use `$phn = $db->EscapeString($phn)` and pass it to the query.

Comment: @BobBrown That's true; I meant to say that *primary* validation should be done server-side (edited the answer). Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I have very little knowledge of programming... I am little confused here. So is it better to enter this validation in the javascript itself? can the whole function be pasted within the script tag? and how can i have the coloring done in the function provided? I thank both of you so much for your contribution and appreciate your help.